# phpmyadmin Cambiar nombre/texto al hover de un id en una tabla, texto que se muestra en tooltip

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tooltip

pequeña consulta en phpmyadmin
Cuando estás en una tabla de myadmin y haces hover sobre una celda que corresponda a un id de otra tabla, él te muestra el texto en tooltip de alguna columna de la tabla relacionada.

Como hago para definir que la columna que quiero ver en ese tooltip es otra?

Gracias

[image: ejemplo en tabla]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes hacerlo de la siguite forma:

1. Tienes que seleccionar la tabla que necesitas que cambie el tooltip en el panel de **phpmyadmin**.

[image: 1]

2. Una vez dentro, en la parte superior selecciona estructura.

[image: 2]

3. Vas a donde dice **vista de relaciones**.

[image: 3]

4. Por último aquí es donde tienes que hacer la referencia a la columna de la tabla que requieres se vea su valor en el tooltip que mencionas.

[image: 4]

> Acá te recomiendo colocar el `ON DELETE` y `ON UPDATE` en `NO ACTION`, así cuando borres registros de una tabla, los registros que tengan referencia a estos no se verán afectados.

Comment: Es incorrecto @Isanchezo Ese proceso es para crear la foráneas con su respectiva afectación, pero no está relacionado a la pregunta